# Fetching URL Params and Rendering a User Page Using Node, React, Express AXIOS AND MONGODB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm trying to write a user profile page to fetch the username from the URL like http://SITE_URL/users/username and use the information to render a Page by comparing the fetched details from database collection but it seems like I am making a huge mistake somewhere around the code.

I am completely new to the MERN stack. Hoping to find a help.

App.js

```
app.get('/users/:username', function (req, res) {
var userurl = req.params.username;
user.findByUsername(userurl,function(result){
//res.send(result);
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/users.html');
}); 
})

app.post('/users/:username', function (req, res) {
var newurl = req.params.username;
user.foundByUsername(newurl,function(result){
res.send(result);
//res.sendFile(__dirname + '/html/users.html');
}); 
})
```

Users.js

```
findByUsername: function(userurl, callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){

        db.collection('user').findOne( { username : userurl 
        },function(err, result){
            if(result==null){
                callback(false)
            }
            else{
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    });
},
foundByUsername: function(newurl, callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){

        db.collection('user').findOne( { username : newurl
        },
        function(err, result){
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Retrived the user entry.");
            if(err == null){
                callback(result)
            }
            else{
                callback(false)
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Users.jsx

```
var Router = window.ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = window.ReactRouter.Route;
var hashHistory = window.ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var browserHistory = window.ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var Link = window.ReactRouter.Link;

class UserProfile extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.foundByUsername = this.foundByUsername.bind(this);
this.state = {
  username: '',
}
}
componentDidMount() {
this.foundByUsername();
}
foundByUsername(){
  var username = this.props.params.username;

  var self = this;

  axios.post('/users/:username', {
    username: username
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    if(response){
    console.log(response);
      self.setState({username:response.data.username});
    }

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error is ',error);
  });

}
render() {
  return (

  <div>
    Username: { this.state.username }<br />

  </div>

  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>

    <Route component={UserProfile} path="/users/:username"></Route> 
</Router>,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: are you sure it's a good idea to connect to the database each time you call those functions?

Comment: I'm new to this stack....and I'm not sure yet what the best practices are

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `create-react-app`, you must proxy all your requests or provide the full url of the server when you make request. For example in your `package.json` add the following

```
"proxy":{
  "/api/*":{
    "target":"http://127.0.0.1:YOUR_PORT_FOR_NODEJS"
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbhiD'y give me some more info on what is actually not working. Where have you got to on debugging?